# How to print spark data frame name on console

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark.

I want to print my spark data frame name on the spark console.
eg: my data frame name in df1. if I try to print it on the console, its getting printed as below:
DataFrame[id: int, name: string]

Do we have any built-in function to print the just data frame name?

Comment: how you printing the dataframe? can you share the code

Comment: Just giving the dataframe name i.e. df1 on console

Comment: you can't print the dataframe name on console, it's like you have no way to print the variable name in any programing language. same as dataframe is also a type of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of pyspark dataframes in a any given spark session as a list of strings. You can then print them or do whatever you like with them

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
allDataFrames = [k for (k, v) in globals().items() if isinstance(v, DataFrame)]
```

Comment: Note that `allDataFrames = [(k, v) for (k, v) in globals().items() if isinstance(v, DataFrame)]` gives the name of the dataframe and the dataframe itself which can be useful for instance to create a dictionary...